# Implied Probability Density with Puts

Tags: options, implied-volatility, probability

The second derivative of the call price at K gives the probability of that strike (implied probability density).

In practice, what adjustments or acknowledgements (if any) need to be made to produce a IPD with puts?

Answer (score 2):

By call-put parity, the second derivative of a European call option price with respect to strike is strictly equivalent to that of a European put.

So, yes: the result, known as the Breeden-Litzenberger identity, stays unchanged.

Comment: Are there any results for American options?

Comment: No, because an American option does not only depend on a terminal probability density.

Comment: Is it actually the same for both? Normally you see different implied forwards from p/c parity at different strikes (I believe due to different margining costs for puts and calls, but not totally sure).

Comment: Theoretically (under the usual assumptions) then yes it should. There is only one conditional pdf $q(s)=d\Bbb{Q}(S_T\leq s)/ds$ after all.